# offsetParent is different

Tags: javascript, css, offset

For chrome and ff this script works perfect, when it comes to the horrible ie. there is a problem

```
function getY(oElement) {
    var curtop = 0;
    if (oElement.offsetParent) {
      while (oElement.offsetParent) 
      {
        curtop += oElement.offsetTop;
        oElement = oElement.offsetParent;
      }
    }
    else if (oElement.y) {
      curtop += oElement.y;
    }
    return curtop;
}
```

I'm tried some debugging and found out that the parent of chrome and ff is `<Li>` which is correct, but the parent of ie is `<body>`

please help anyone?

Ok, i did some more digging and found that ie doesnt support `offsetparent` with `position:relative;` but I do need this css for other reason, any walkaround?

Comment: Here's how jQuery does it: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/offset.js#L213 (you can search the jQuery source for `"offsetParent:"` to find that part yourself)

Answer (score 0):

I used to use a script similar to this all the time to determine the position of the element. Since then I have moved to using jQuery which has two awesome and very cross browser compliant functions for determining position:

position() - http://api.jquery.com/position/ - gets the position of the element relative to the parent.

offset() - [http://api.jquery.com/offset/](http://api.jquery.com/position/) - gets the position of the element relative to the document.

I was a little reluctant to use jQuery at first because I didn't want to spend the time learning it and because I'd already written so many code snippets on my own that did things like this. When I did try jQuery I learned it within a day and I love it and now use it for all my JavaScript projects.

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but jQuery does have position finding functions.